# DataTables not working in .php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

Hello I have the following table and I wish to turn it into a DataTable.

```
<?php require 'bootstrap.php';?>
  <!doctype html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Service Centres</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 align="center">Service Centres</h1>
    <table border="1" align="center" id="service_table" class="display">
      <tr>
        <th>Centre Postcode</th>
        <th>Centre Type</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12345</td>
        <td>Standard</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12345</td>
        <td>Standard</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12345</td>
        <td>Standard</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(
        function() {
          $('#service_table').DataTable();
        });

    </script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

However for some reason this does not work. I notice my table change if I don't include the script part, but it does not have any sort/search features and just becomes as wide as the whole screen for some reason.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Here it is on fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6pye363h/1/

Comment: Do you have jquery included before the datatable js file?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still learning how to do all this. I don't think so? How do I include jquery?

Comment: Are you using also the `DataTable API` or just `dataTable`. Note that `DataTable` and `dataTable` are two different things.

Comment: I don't know. I want to use this one: https://datatables.net/ which one is it? Sorry for not being clear

Comment: @Hokkaido look at the answer I gave you, I explained you why it didn't work and gave you a working DEMO. you welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a few things to make datatable work:

1. Load Jquery before the Datatable js file.
2. Load DataTable js + css.
3. Your table must have a **Thead** and a **Tbody**
4. Add  `$('#service_table').DataTable();` in your javascript.

The problem with your code was that you didn't include JQuery and your table didn't have **Thead** and **Tbody**.

Here is a working [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/JsrTueqka3CY3O7DclNo?p=preview) for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
<table border="1" align="center" id="service_table" class="display">
  <thead> <---------------------
  <tr>
    <th>Centre Postcode</th>
    <th>Centre Type</th>
  </tr>
  </thead> <---------------------
  <tbody> <---------------------
  <tr>
    <td>12345</td>
    <td>Standard</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12345</td>
    <td>Standard</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12345</td>
    <td>Standard</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody> <---------------------
</table>
```

Add the indicated lines to your code

Also place

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Into your header